# SQL: Conditionally join on a date table if value found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return the columns found in a date dimension, if the values in my columns in a separate dimension are valid and match keys in the date dimension. But, I want to do this conditionally, checking first for `attributeOne` and whether or not a date key exists there that can map the date dimension, then checking `attributeTwo`, and so on.

How can I specify a join to the date dimension such that all possible columns that I want to check join if found (e.g., `attributeOne`, `attributeTwo`, `attributeThree`, etc) so I can conditionally report/return the date dimension columns for that match.

```
JOIN #date D on D.dateKey = d1.attributeOne;
```

Consider this probably far too contrived example:

```
drop table #date;
drop table #dim;
drop table #fact;

    CREATE TABLE #date (dateKey int, dateVal varchar(25))
    INSERT  #date (dateKey, dateVal) 
    VALUES 
    (20000101, 'FY1')
    ,(20000102, 'FY2')
    ,(20000103, 'FY3')
    ,(20000104, 'FY4')
    ,(20000105, 'FY5')

    CREATE TABLE #dim (dKey int, attributeOne int, attributeTwo int, attributeThree int)
    INSERT  #dim (dKey, attributeOne, attributeTwo, attributeThree)
    VALUES 
    (1, 20000101, 20000102, NULL)
    ,(2, NULL, 20000104, 20000105)
    ,(3, 20000301, 20000501, 20000104)
    ,(4, NULL, 20000102, NULL)

    CREATE TABLE #fact (fKey int, Naming varchar(25))
    INSERT  #fact (fKey, Naming)
    VALUES 
    (1, 'ex1')
    ,(2, 'ex2')
    ,(3, 'ex3')
    ,(4, 'ex4')

-- how to 
select
f.fKey as 'F Key',
CASE 
    WHEN d1.attributeOne = D.dateKey THEN D.dateVal
    WHEN d1.attributeTwo = D.dateKey THEN D.dateVal
    WHEN d1.attributeThree = D.dateKey THEN D.dateVal
    ELSE '<missing>' END AS "attributeOne"
from #fact f
JOIN #dim d1 on f.fKey = d1.dKey
JOIN #date D on D.dateKey = d1.attributeOne;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like joining on an `IN` with some conditional aggregation?

> ```
> select fact.Naming
> , MAX(CASE WHEN dim.attributeOne = dt.dateKey THEN dt.dateVal WHEN dim.attributeOne IS NOT NULL THEN '<missing>' ELSE '' END) AS attributeOne
> , MAX(CASE WHEN dim.attributeTwo = dt.dateKey THEN dt.dateVal WHEN dim.attributeTwo IS NOT NULL THEN '<missing>' ELSE '' END) AS attributeTwo
> , MAX(CASE WHEN dim.attributeThree = dt.dateKey THEN dt.dateVal WHEN dim.attributeThree IS NOT NULL THEN '<missing>' ELSE '' END) AS attributeThree
> FROM #fact AS fact
> LEFT JOIN #dim AS dim 
>   ON dim.dKey = fact.fKey
> LEFT JOIN #date AS dt 
>   ON dt.dateKey IN (dim.attributeOne, dim.attributeTwo, dim.attributeThree)
> GROUP BY fact.fKey, fact.Naming
> ORDER BY fact.fKey
> ```
>
> ```
> Naming | attributeOne | attributeTwo | attributeThree
> :----- | :----------- | :----------- | :-------------
> ex1    | FY1          | FY2          |               
> ex2    |              | FY4          | FY5           
> ex3    | <missing>    | <missing>    | FY4           
> ex4    |              | FY2          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7acd11f1e2a456a30f95b2360294f9fc)*